# Can't create an HTML file with PHP

Tags: php, html, function, file-io

I'm trying to create an .html file using PHP, and filling it with the content of an array, but I can't create the html file. Here's my function:

```
function viewPag(){
    session_start();

    $handler=fopen("view.php", 'w+');

    for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION["Text"]); $i++) { 
        fwrite($handler,$_SESSION["Text"][$i]);
    }

    fclose($handler);

    header("Location: view.php");
}
```

Comment: If the file is not created I suggest 1. you check the http servers error log file and 2. you implement error handling. Most likely you have a permission problem.

Comment: What do you mean that you can't create? What happens?

Comment: You are right arkascha, it was a permission problem...

Comment: @Doruko what filesystem / OS do you have?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Server right now

Answer (score 1):

You can't run PHP inside `.html` file. But, You can do it by editing `.htaccess` file.

Save the file with `.php` extension and edit the `.htaccess` file as following.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

If you want to use it in only one page you can use the following code.

```
<Files yourpage.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are not on the folder you think. use `echo getcwd();` to print the current folder, and then use a relative path to store the file where you want.

It also may be that your `fopen` call is failing due to permission issues. Add an `if` to test the `$handler` value after the `fopen` call:

```
if (!$handler) {
    echo "Could not open file for writing. Aborting";
    die();
}
```

And one thing you should really do is look at your logs and search for errors. Withouth looking at the logs you (and we) are just blind and don't know what is failing (maybe what fails is something before this function... we can't know for sure).